# How does express know to run "server.js"?

Tags: node.js, express

I cracked open an experimental express project I hadn't touched for a couple of months, and I tried to trace through how everything works to refresh my understanding.

What confuses is me is that my express app is run from a file called server.js, but that is not specified anywhere in my package.json, nor is there any reference to such a filename (like as a default) in the node_modules folder for express. It works though, unless I rename the file (e.g. server_.js). I have no scripts setup in package.json. Whatever I specify for "main" in package.json seems to have no effect.

So how does npm start know to run the app from server.js?

```
{
  "name": "my thing",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "This is my thing.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my-thing"
  },
  "author": "Faust",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-alpha.19",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

ls of the root:
`data/  entry.jsx  node_modules/  npm-debug.log  package.json  public/  server.js  src/ webpack.config.js`

Comment: I believe npm uses package.json to figure out what to do with npm start. The npm start command is probably followed by a " : node server.js" to start the server.

Comment: hm, weird ! It could be an index.js in the root files that does the job.. We need to know the `-ls` of your root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official NPM docs -

> npm start runs an arbitrary command specified in the package's "start" property of its "scripts" object. If no "start" property is specified on the "scripts" object, it will run node server.js.

Read more [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start#description).